# How to replace blank cells in each row with a unique value

Tags: vba, excel

I've got an Excel file that looks like this:

```
 Person1,Person2,Person3,Person4,Median
 GeneA 1,0,2,,1
 GeneB 1,,2,1,1
 GeneC 2,,,0,0
 GeneD 0,1,1,2,1
 GeneE 0,0,0,,0
```

The 5th column is the median for each row. I would like to replace the missing data in each row with this median value.

Any ideas for how I could go about doing this? I've got over 160 columns and 60,000 rows of data.

Comment: If you're able to calculate the median in the spreadsheet, look at the =MEDIAN() function.

If you want to calculate the median in VBA, you can call the WorksheetFunction.Median method. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-median-method-excel

Comment: why not a simple `IF` statement, copy/pasted down all your rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how one `IF` statement can be used to fill in the blanks:

[image: animated screenshot example]

Also, a note on your medians:  perhaps these aren't the actual calculations, but at least one of your sample rows has an incorrect median.  Excel has a built-in function to calculate `MEDIAN` (which you could even use instead of the `IF` statement, if filling in the blank is the only goal).

---

### More Information:

- Wikipedia : **[Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)**
- Office.com : **[`IF` Function (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)**
- Office.com : **[`MEDIAN` Function (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/median-function-d0916313-4753-414c-8537-ce85bdd967d2)**

Answer (score 1):

a VBA solution

```
Sub main()
    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:F"))
        .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC6"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one - I always forget about fun things the `SpecialCells` method can do.

Comment: @ashleedawg, yes they can be handy sometimes